# unzip file without using `unzip` on Linux on a file zipped on Windows

Tags: bash, zip, unzip, rhel-7

When using `unzip` in Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) to deflate an 8.8Gb zip file created on a Windows 10 64-bit system, I am getting an error `bad CRC eb71d36a  (should be b0968d02)`.  The single text file contained in the zip file does get extracted, but it is corrupted.

I can unzip the exact same zip file on a Windows 10 64-bit computer with 7z, without any issues, then `sftp` or `scp` that file to the same RHEL computer, and it works just fine.  However, this is not a viable long term solution.

Nearly identical details of this error are documented on the following websites:

1. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153011
2. https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=5451&sid=99b599f3615126e1dc48d671468336d8&start=10

They both seem to document an unaddressed bug in unzip.

So the question is:
From a RHEL bash shell, how can I unzip a large zip file that was zipped on a Windows 10 64-bit system without using `unzip`?

I have tried the following, which produces the errors shown:

```bsh
$ gunzip -S .zip largefile.zip
gzip: largefile.zip: first entry not deflated or stored -- use unzip
```

```bsh
$ jar -xvf largefile.zip
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid compression method
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:224)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:139)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:1015)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:924)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:264)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1231)
```

---

Linux version

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
Release:        7.3
Codename:       Maipo
```

unzip version

```
$ unzip -v
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/ ;
see ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/UnZip.html for other sites.

Compiled with gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) for Unix (Linux ELF) on Apr 15 2016.
```

Comment: Maybe that file was made with 7Zip for Windows https://www.7-zip.org/ , using a mode not included in unzip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have 7z on the RHEL server? Otherwise you can use that to extract the zip file.

```bsh
7z e archive.zip
```

Comment: Before you ask the sys admin, you could compile it in your home directory and test it first.